# MSP430F5137 SPI-UART Bridge

Tags: c++, uart, spi, msp430, code-composer

I am working on a SPI-UART bridge connection with an MSP430F5133 to RHD2132. The code was compiled using Code Compose Studio. This is the current code I have but I am still having issues

```
#include <msp430.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint16_t convert_intan(uint8_t channel);                                // Function that receives 16 bit
uint16_t transfer_16_bit_MOSI(uint16_t command);                        // Function that recieves data

void calibrate_intan(void);                     // Function that send calibrate command
void initialize_clk(void);                      // Clock initialize function
void initialize_pin(void);                      // Pin initialize function

int main(void)
{
    uint8_t j =0;                               // Shifting variable
    uint16_t data[99];                          // Values stored from transfer

    WDTCTL = WDTPW | WDTHOLD;                   // stop watchdog timer

    initialize_pin();                           // Initialize pin configuration
    initialize_clk();                           // Initialize clock configuration
    calibrate_intan();                          // Calibration

    data[j] = convert_intan(0);                 // Initial data transfer

    while(1)
    {
        data[j] = convert_intan(63);
        j++;
        if(j == 31)
           {j = 0;}
    }
    return 0;
}

void initialize_clk(void)
{
    UCSCTL3 |= SELREF_2;                        // Set DCO FLL reference = REFO
    UCSCTL4 |= SELA_2;                          // Set ACLK = REFO

    __bis_SR_register(SCG0);                    // Disable the FLL control loop
    UCSCTL0 = 0x0000;                           // Set lowest possible DCOx, MODx
    UCSCTL1 = DCORSEL_5;                        // Select DCO range 16MHz operation
    UCSCTL2 = FLLD_1 +  249;                    // Set DCO Multiplier for 8MHz
                                                // (N + 1) * FLLRef = Fdco
                                                // (249 + 1) * 32768 = 8192000Hz
                                                // Set FLL Div = fDCOCLK/2
    __bic_SR_register(SCG0);                    // Enable the FLL control loop

    UCA0CTL1 |= UCSWRST;                        // **Put state machine in reset**
    UCA0CTL1 |= UCSSEL_1;                       // CLK = ACLK
    UCA0BR0 = 0x03;                             // 32k/9600 - 3.41
    UCA0BR1 = 0x00;                             //
    UCA0MCTL = 0x06;                            // Modulation
    UCA0CTL1 &= ~UCSWRST;                       // **Initialize USCI state machine**
    UCA0IE |= UCRXIE + UCTXIE;                  // enable interrupt flags

    UCB0CTL1 |= UCSWRST;                        // Set in reset state so that config can be added
    UCB0CTL0 = UCMST+UCSYNC+UCCKPL+UCMSB;       // 3-pin, 8-bit SPI master
    UCB0CTL1 = UCSSEL_2;                        // SMCLK
    UCB0BR0 = 0x02;                             // SPI same clock as SMCLK/1 (8Mhz)
    UCB0BR1 = 0x00;                             //
    UCB0CTL1 &= ~UCSWRST;                       // **Initialize USCI state machine** Effectively starting SPI communication, now only need to pull CS low when sending data
    UCB0IE |= UCRXIE + UCTXIE;                  // enable interrupt flags

    do
    {
      UCSCTL7 &= ~(XT1LFOFFG + DCOFFG);         // Clear XT2,XT1,DCO fault flags
      SFRIFG1 &= ~OFIFG;                        // Clear fault flags
      __delay_cycles(100000);                   // Delay for Osc to stabilize
    }while (SFRIFG1&OFIFG);                     // Test oscillator fault flag

}

void initialize_pin(void)
{
    PMAPPWD = 0x02D52;                          // Get write-access to port mapping register
    P1MAP2 = PM_UCB0SOMI;                       // Map UCB0SOMI output to P1.2
    P1MAP3 = PM_UCB0SIMO;                       // Map UCB0SIMO output to P1.3
    P1MAP4 = PM_UCB0CLK;                        // Map UCB0CLK output to P1.4
    P2MAP6 = PM_UCA0RXD;                        // Map UCA0RXD output to P2.6
    P2MAP7 = PM_UCA0TXD;                        // Map UCA0TXD output to P2.7
    PMAPPWD = 0;                                // Lock port mapping registers

    P1DIR |= BIT0;                              // Set as output pin    [1.4:CS]
    P1DIR |= BIT2 + BIT3 + BIT4;                // Set UCIB_0           [1.2:SIMO][1.3:MOSI][1.4:SCLK]
    P2DIR |= BIT7;                              // Set as TX output     [2.7:DMAE0]
    P3DIR |= BIT7;                              // Set as output        [3.7:SMCLK]

    P1OUT &= ~BIT0;                             // Sets CS high
    P1SEL |= BIT2 + BIT3 + BIT4;                // Enable SPI function
    P2SEL |= BIT6 + BIT7;                       // Enable UART function
    P3SEL |= BIT7;                              // Enable SPI CLK
    P5SEL |= 0x03;                              // Enable XT1 pins
}

void calibrate_intan(void)
{
    uint16_t result,temp;
    uint8_t m =9;

    result = transfer_16_bit_MOSI(0x5500);      // Calibrate on datasheet is command: (0101  0101  0000  0000) which is equivalent to  0x5500

    for(; m > 0; m--)                           // Sends 9 dummy commands to complete calibration cycle
    {temp = transfer_16_bit_MOSI(0x0010);}
}

uint16_t convert_intan(uint8_t channel)
{
    uint16_t command;                           // 16 bit senting
    uint8_t static const convert_mask = 0x00;   // Mask to write to keep "00" at MSBits

    command = (((convert_mask | channel) << 8 ) | (0x00));      // Creates command

    return transfer_16_bit_MOSI(command);
}

uint16_t transfer_16_bit_MOSI(uint16_t command)
{
    uint8_t hi = ((command>>8)&0xff);
    uint8_t lo = ((command>>0)&0xff);
    uint8_t bytes_RX_buffer[2];                 // Stores received data

    P1OUT |= BIT0;                              // Sets CS low

    while (!(UCB0IFG&UCTXIFG));                 // USCI_B0 TX buffer ready?
    {UCB0TXBUF = hi;}                           // Send first 8 bits of command over SPI to Slave
    while (!(UCB0IFG&UCTXIFG));                 // USCI_B0 TX buffer ready?
    {UCB0TXBUF = lo;}                           // Send last 8 bits of command over SPI to Slave

    P1OUT &= ~BIT0;                             // Sets CS high
    _delay_cycles(15);
    P1OUT |= BIT0;                              // Sets CS low

    while (!(UCB0IFG&UCRXIFG));                 // USCI_B0 RX Received?
    {bytes_RX_buffer[1] = UCB0RXBUF;}           // Store received data
    while (!(UCB0IFG&UCRXIFG));                 // USCI_B0 RX Received?
    {bytes_RX_buffer[0] = UCB0RXBUF;}           // Store received data

    P1OUT &= ~BIT0;                             // Sets CS high

    while (!(UCA0IFG&UCTXIFG));                 // USCI_B0 TX buffer ready?
    {UCA0TXBUF = bytes_RX_buffer[0];}           // Send first 8 bits of command over UART
    while (!(UCA0IFG&UCTXIFG));                 // USCI_B0 TX buffer ready?
    {UCA0TXBUF = bytes_RX_buffer[1];}           // Send last 8 bits of command over UART

    return ((bytes_RX_buffer[1] << 8) | bytes_RX_buffer[0]);
}
```

The rx and tx buffers require 8 bits hence the conversions and currently I am looking to obtain a frequency of 8Mhz for the SPI sclk. I am not sure if it is hardware or software, the code compiles but I don't receive data from the slave.

Comment: Does P1OUT.BIT0 works on inverse logic? Comments and bit values are the opposite.

Comment: Well after some testing I found a better way to code it. But i am suspecting my issues revolve around SMCLK as i use it as the CLK of the SPI system `code`

Comment: While the output of the SMCLK pin is correct on 8Mhz is there an error configuring the SPI CLK as the SMCLK?

Comment: Cannot test it here, but SMCLK should be OK. Why are you enabling interrupts? Without a proper Interrupt handler this will be an issue when you enable GIE on the CPU.

Comment: I am not sure how the peripheral works, but in SPI you should make a "Put" and a "Get" for every byte transferred or you will have one of the error bits in UCAxSTAT active. Unused bytes should be simply discarded, but internal state machine wants the "Get". This is also critical on the first part where you transmit your bytes, since you change the CS line without checking that the transfer finalized (i.e. get). After the "put" CPU will run in parallel to the SPI hardware and your CS line will switch while bits are flowing (SLAU208Q-37.3.3)

Comment: Your P1.0 can be managed automatically by hardware throught the UCxSTE signal. See SLAU208Q 37.3.6.1, figure 37-4.